# Barcode is not getting scanned through my scanner machine in mvc.net application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have generated my barcode image through code 39 when i going to scan image on my desktop then its not getting scanned.And Also not working when i print that Barcode image and scan after.

```
public Byte[] getBarcodeImage(string barcode, string file) 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        BarCode39 _barcode = new BarCode39(); int barSize =25; 
        string fontFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/fonts/FREE3OF9.TTF"); 
        return (_barcode.Code39(barcode, barSize, true, file, fontFile)); 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) { } 
    return null; 
}
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: I have a barcodecs as follows    public Byte[] getBarcodeImage(string barcode, string file)
        {
            try
            {
                BarCode39 _barcode = new BarCode39();
                int barSize =25;
                string fontFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/fonts/FREE3OF9.TTF");
                return (_barcode.Code39(barcode, barSize, true, file, fontFile));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              
            }
            return null;
        }

Comment: It s generate image but generated image is not getting scanned.Please help me to solve this problem.Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error BarcodeImage is getting successfully,But not getting scanned through Scanner.

Comment: when i printed out this all images and trying to scan those images but i fail.

Answer (score 0):

According to  [this article and the comments within](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/749557/Generate-Bar-Code-Using-ASP-NET-MVC) you first need to increase the bar size. I set mine at `64`. Then you need to add `*` character to beginning and end of barcode image like this: `return (_barcode.Code39($"*{barcode}*", barSize, true, file, fontFile));` This should work and when you scan you get your barcode without the `*` characters.